# Broadcast express session expiration to web client

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express.session to set the expiry of the session. Since there is a session maintain between server and client, is it possible for node server to broadcast to client to notify that the client session is going to expire(Eg: 5 minutes before expiry)?

1) A session is established between node server and client. Session in server is stored in mongodb. 
2) When session is going to expire 5 minutes before, server send notifications to client.
3) Client browser prompt an alert box to user.

```
app.use(express.session({
    cookie  : { maxAge  : new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000 * 30)) }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way is to try using `socket.io` to emit a 'checkSessionExpiration' call every 1 minute on client side.

```
setInterval(function() {
    socket.emit('checkSessionExpiration');
}, 60 * 1000);

socket.on('sessionAlert', function ()) {
    alert('session will expire in ...');
}
```

On server side, you will able to check if the session will expire soon.

```
socket.on('checkSessionExpiration', function () {
    // check the session here and emit a sessionAlert

    // if session will expire soon
    socket.emit('sessionAlert');
}
```

Comment: Lets say i have 10000 client connected at a same time. Then they will be 10000 call to the server every minute. I think this is heavy load to server (not sure if). Also, i guess there will always be a condition where the socket fail to emit if using interval based in client?